# User-defined function to create a dataset

Tags: python

My task is to use a given user-defined function to create a dataset for a specific region.

I've insert my specific data in the function

But only got this error:

`KeyError: "[' magType ' ' nst' ' gap' ' dmin ' ' rms' ' place ' ' type '\n ' horizontalError ' ' depthError ' ' magError ' ' magNst ' ' status '\n ' locationSource ' ' magSource ' ' net' 'id' ' updated '] not found in axis"`

How do I solve this problem? Because when I look at my data I got all this information (magType etc.)

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. If you're sure that all those keys are present in your data, then you should be able to `.drop` them one at a time, right? Does that work? No? Which key failed? Have you considered the possibility that sometimes your data will have all these keys and other times it won't, depending on the CSV contents? Anyway, we can't tell you why your data isn't behaving because we don't have your data.

Comment: There is a lot of very strange spacing in your code. You should examine that carefully. Some spaces - such as the ones inside your string literals - are meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the columns you have for the `pd.DataFrame` you fetch from the url are;

`['time', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'depth', 'mag', 'magType', 'nst', 'gap', 'dmin', 'rms', 'net', 'id', 'updated', 'place', 'type', 'horizontalError', 'depthError', 'magError', 'magNst', 'status', 'locationSource', 'magSource']`

Which does not match with the column names you inserted into the `drop` function. Reformat the column names `[" magType "," nst"," gap"," dmin "," rms"," place "," type " ," horizontalError "," depthError "," magError "," magNst "," status "," locationSource "," magSource "," net","id"," updated "]` in the drop function exactly matching with your `pd.DataFrame` object `data`.

PS: You might wanna look into `fstrings` or `.format`. That will make your code look a lot cleaner.

Second PS: You also might want to not recursively concatanate `data`. As `data` gets bigger, the process will be remarkable slower. The better way to do it is create a list (e.g. `dfList`) and append the list with the dataframes you fetch from the urls. And then use the function `pd.concat(dfList)`. Cheers!

Comment: oh dear I did not notice that, thank you very much!